# systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility

Tags: raspbian, rc

I'm using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi, and I see this error when booting up the system:

```
Nov 25 20:30:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Nov 25 20:30:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Nov 25 20:30:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit rc-local.service entered failed state.
```

The only changes I know that I have done to `/etc/rc.local` is to add these arguments to allow a VPN connection (before `exit 0`). When they are commented out, I get no error:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i vpn -j ACCEPT
iptables6 -I INPUT 1 -i vpn -j ACCEPT
```

What does the error message imply and what should I do about it?

Comment: What happens if you comment out those lines and reboot?  Do you still get the systemd failure?

Comment: @RobertL Thanks for your reply - I don't see the errors with those lines commented out.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

1. try to use the absolute path like `/sbin/iptables`,
2. try to verify your `vpn` is a valid interface.

Comment: 127 is the exit status `sh` uses for "command not found", so yeah, definitely check the path.